# Beginning learning Cocos2D, any recommendable resources?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm beginning to learn Cocos2D, I am personally more of a visual learner so if anyone knows of any good video tutorials they could direct me to, I would very much appreciate it :)

Thank you in advance for your time and any help :)

Comment: check my youtube channel (learncocos2d) and there the recommended channels, specifically the new boston. Keep in mind that most video tuts are far more out of date than articles.

Comment: dont forget to read the answers to the question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711268/requirements-for-learning-cocos2d/14711635#14711635

Answer (score 3):

First off, Cocos2D is an excellent and (relatively) easy engine to get your head around. Good choice! I would highly recommend the book by Steffen Itterheim found [here](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com). In just a few days I felt good about using the engine. A few months later, it is second nature. Also check out Kobold2D, which is an extension of Cocos2D that handles a lot of the annoying nitty-gritty stuff for you. Also, [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com) has a whole host of Cocos2D online tutorials, but not all of them are up to date with the latest releases.

Answer (score 0):

There is a blog post about good resources to get you started [here](http://woohoogames.wordpress.com/2013/02/10/beginning-cocos2d/).